How to set cookies with Express in Next.Js server actions
I am setting cookies via the Express.Js backend server, and the response shows set-cookie, but I am using Next.js 15 on the client, and cookies are not set.
Even though I read somewhere that server actions are being executed on server components.
I need suggestions on setting cookies via set-cookie.
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
res.clearCookie("authToken");
res.cookie("authToken", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: date,
  path: "/",
  sameSite: "none",
});

Here is the server action login function (included use server at the top)
try {
  const res = await axiosInstance.request({
      url: "/auth/login",
      method: "POST",
      data: { name, email, password },
    });
  console.log(res);
  console.log("Request successful:login ", res.data);
  return res.data;
} catch(error) {
  console.log("Error while signup: => ", error);
  throw error;
}

form:
<form action={handleSubmit}>


cookies in next js is a important part of this and in next js 13-14 and 15, next js team hasn't completed it.
so we have some problems in setting cookies in route handler and server actions.
you can set it with this code:
'use server'

import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function cookie_setter(name: string, value: string,time:number) {

   (await cookies()).set({
      name: name,
      value: value,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      path: "/",
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + time)
   });

   return 1
}

I used this code in my website https://mernfa.ir/nextjs-learning and you can see it's working in it's working authentication part....
